# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type Event when searching from cloudkit

Tags: swift, search, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm trying to add a function to my ios app in which the user can search through the list of countries available in CloudKit. To do that I created a search field and I'm trying to read the data available CloudKit and retrieve it but I'm getting the following error.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type Event
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plibL.png) is the exact location of the error. I'm new to this whole swift thing so I need some help.

This is the page with the search field

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

struct Event: Identifiable{
    let record: CKRecord
    let id: CKRecord.ID
    let Country: String
    let dateTime : Date
    
    init(record: CKRecord){
        self.record = record
        self.id = record.recordID
        self.Country = record["Country"] as? String ?? ""
        self.dateTime = record["dateTime"] as? Date ?? Date.now
    }
}
struct NewCity: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showingNatio = false
    @State private var showingNotifi = false
    @State var events :[Event] = [] 
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Search for a country")
                    .font(.title.weight(.bold))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .searchable(text: $searchText){
                        ForEach(events) { city in
                            RowView(city: city)
                        }
                    }.onChange(of: searchText) { searchText in
                        events = events.filter({ city in
                            city.Country.lowercased().contains(searchText)
                        })
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Countries")
                Text("Start searching for a country \n to add it to your list")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
    func fetchEvent(){
        events.removeAll()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType:"Event", predicate: predicate)
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.recordMatchedBlock = {recordID, result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let record):
                let event = Event(record: record)
                events.append(event)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
        
    }
}

struct NewCity_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewCity()
    }
}
```

This page is the row view which displays the format of each row when searched for

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct RowView: View {
    var city: Event
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text (city.Country)
                    .font(.title2.weight(.semibold))
            }
        }
    }
}
struct RowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RowView(city: Event.Country)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Comment: To make your code easier to parse, always use `lowerCamelCase` for properties in Swift, so `let country` rather than `let Country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `struct RowView` is defined as follows:

```
struct RowView: View {
    var city: Event
    // etc
```

So its initialiser takes an `Event`

```
init(city: Event)
```

You're calling it as follows:

```
RowView(city: Event.Country)
```

and `Event.Country` is defined as:

```
let Country: String
```

i.e a `String`

hence the error message.

You need to pass an `Event` when you create a `RowView`